# Angular: Reading json from web-api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to create an Angular service to load JSON data from my Web API but I have no idea how to do this. The data looks like this:

```
{"employees":[{"id":1,"name":"Peter"},{"id":2,"name":"Paul"}]}
```

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I am sorry. I understand what the functions are doing. But there is nowhere an explenation where I have to write the stuff in. In my component or in an extra service or... It's just partly helping me.

Comment: If you want to load it at startup, you have to write in in the ngOnInit method, else write it in the function which is responsible of calling the api to load your data. You should do the tour of heroes tutorial (angular.io/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Use http.get method to get data from the web services.

```
this.http.get('pass your url')
.subscribe(
   data => {
   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
},
error => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: in which function do you use this? what kind of object is 'data'? thanks for helping!

Comment: Create a function where you want to get the response of the web-api and data is the response that you are getting ... you can extract the json from your response ... just check whatever response you are getting and parse it to json.

Comment: You can write this function in your service as well as in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to

1. Create a service which get's the JSON data from URL
2. Call that service in your component
3. Use string interpolation to display that data

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/apijsonresponse?file=src/app/app.component.ts) the link to stackblitz code.